# My css and image files are being blocked and don't show in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, oracle-adf, mixed-content

Chrome is blocking the `css` files and `images` from showing by generating this error in its console:

```
This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS
```

I have all my routes to the CSS files with relative paths:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../resources/css/template.css"/>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../resources/css/menu.css"/>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../resources/css/general.css"/>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../resources/css/system.css"/>
```

But there is a token (a token for maintaining the application state) added to the path (as this is ADF)

so chrome finds this:

```
'http://my.site.com/package/faces/resources/css/template.css?_adf.ctrl-state=q0l98h1nm_125'
```

I don't know how (I searched all my project and there's nothing that has a non-relative path)

I think, maybe the added token mixes it all for chrome?:

`?_adf.ctrl-state=q0l98h1nm_125`

### Problem:

All the styles and images are blocked form the site, nothing shows, only letters (but in firefox shows it perfectly)

As you see in the html tags, all the css files I have have relative paths and I think that the browser should already decide to attach it the proper protocol, i.e the main protocol of the request.

### Question:

How to resolve the problem?

Comment: FYI: The part behind '?' is a token -> provided by ADF controller to identify the current user state. This token is used to retrieve the user state within the task flow. Can you access the .css file in Chrome using the URL?

Comment: @User404 yes of course

Comment: Is it a cross domain request?

Comment: @AbleJohnson no, all the css files are with in the application, they are the usual css files that come with the adf application

Comment: my application runs over https